# ansible identifying UID < 500 and making their shell as /sbin/nologin

Tags: ansible

```
- name: 5.4.2 Ensure system accounts are non-login
    shell: for USER in $(awk -F':' '$3 < 1500 && $NF ~ /\/bin\/bash/ && $1 !~ /^root/ {print $1}' /etc/passwd);do echo $USER; done;
    when: ansible_distribution_major_version == "7"
    register: user_status
    ignore_errors: true
```

here i can get output in stdout , but still i cannot able to set shell

Comment: Hi sri, welcome to SO. You will want to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64484667/edit) and include what **is** happening when you run that, because we are not on your machine in order to see what you see, or to know what, specifically, you are requesting help fixing. Good luck!

Comment: try replacing `echo` with `usermod --shell /sbin/nologin $USER` and run the task  with `become: true`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of *shell* use [*getent*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/getent_module.html#ansible-builtin-getent-a-wrapper-to-the-unix-getent-utility) and create "{uid: user}" dictionary. For example

```yaml
    - getent:
        database: passwd
    - set_fact:
        my_dict: "{{ dict(my_uids|zip(my_usrs)) }}"
      vars:
        my_usrs: "{{ getent_passwd.keys()|list }}"
        my_uids: "{{ getent_passwd|dict2items|
                     json_query('[].value[1]')|
                     map('int')|list }}"
```

Then you can use the dictionary to select users by the uids. For example, given /etc/passwd below

```sh
shell> cat /etc/passwd
...
user1:*:1002:1002:User &:/home/user1:/bin/sh
user2:*:1003:1003:User &:/home/user2:/bin/sh
admin9:*:1004:1004:admin:/home/admin9:/bin/sh
```

the task below selects users from the uid range

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.value }}"
      loop: "{{ my_dict|dict2items|
                selectattr('key', 'ge', uid_from)|
                selectattr('key', 'le', uid_to)|
                list }}"
      vars:
        uid_from: 1002
        uid_to: 1005
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: user1
  msg: user2
  msg: admin9
```

If this is what you want the next task will change the login shell for the selected users

```yaml
    - user:
        name: "{{ item.value }}"
        shell: /usr/sbin/nologin
      loop: "{{ my_dict|dict2items|
                selectattr('key', 'ge', uid_from)|
                selectattr('key', 'le', uid_to)|
                list }}"
      vars:
        uid_from: 1002
        uid_to: 1005
```

```sh
shell> cat /etc/passwd
...
user1:*:1002:1002:User &:/home/user1:/usr/sbin/nologin
user2:*:1003:1003:User &:/home/user2:/usr/sbin/nologin
admin9:*:1004:1004:admin:/home/admin9:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

---

The task is simpler for a list of uids

```yaml
    - user:
        name: "{{ my_dict[item] }}"
        shell: /usr/sbin/nologin
      loop: [1002, 1003, 1004]
```